# RxBinding TextChanges won't continue emitting text changes

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-binding

Trying to figure out why RxTextView.textChanges only emits the initial value.  My understanding is that it should emit all new text changes to downstream subscriptions.

Here is the code

```
    public class SignupFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.text_name) EditText txtName;
    @BindView(R.id.text_email) EditText txtEmail;
    @BindView(R.id.text_password) EditText txtPassword;
    @BindView(R.id.text_confirm_password) EditText txtConfirmPassword;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_signup) Button btnSignup;
    SignupViewModel viewModel;
    private CompositeDisposable disposables;

    FragmentSignupBinding binding;
    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        this.disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

        RxTextView.textChanges(txtEmail)
                .subscribe(new Observer<CharSequence>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(CharSequence charSequence) {
                        Log.d("Subscription", charSequence.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.d("Subscription", "On Complete");
                    }
                });

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SignupViewModel.class);
        viewModel.applyInputs(RxTextView.textChanges(txtName),
                RxTextView.textChanges(txtEmail),
                RxTextView.textChanges(txtPassword),
                RxTextView.textChanges(txtConfirmPassword),
                RxView.clicks(btnSignup));


        Disposable validInputs =
        viewModel.validInputs()
                .doOnNext(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
                    @SuppressLint("TimberArgCount")
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Boolean aBoolean) throws Exception {
                        Timber.d("Valid inputs: %b", aBoolean.booleanValue());
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(RxView.visibility(btnSignup));

        disposables.add(validInputs);

        FragmentSignupBinding binding = FragmentSignupBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.disposables.dispose();
    }
}
```

This previously was edited down to focus on where I thought the issue was.  This is now the complete picture.

Comment: looks ok to me, can you post the full code?

Comment: Added the full code for the fragment.  Only left things out as I was trying to simplify the code.  End state I want these observables to be sent into the viewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't handling the Fragment Data Binding correctly.  At this point in the code it wasn't even necessary.  I didn't realize that setup could affect the RxBindingings.

Following code was broken...

```
 @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);
...

        FragmentSignupBinding binding = FragmentSignupBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }
```

Following code works now....

```
    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentSignupBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        this.disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
....
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    RxTextView.textChanges(txtEmail)
            .subscribe(new Observer<CharSequence>() {
```

This is wrong, should be

```
disposables.add(RxTextView.textChanges(txtEmail)
        .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<CharSequence>() {
```

---

Also, `RxView.clicks(` for example can support only 1 listener, because it wraps `setOnClickListener()` method.

So there is a good chance that your code would work like so

```
Observable<CharSequence> obsName;

...
public void onCreate(...) {
    ...
    obsName = RxTextView.textChanges(txtName).share();
```

and then use `obsName` wherever, same for the other `Rx___` calls you have.

Comment: This is totally accurate and its how the code looks now, but this wasn't what created the issue.  It really had nothing to do with the way I was setting up the observables and more to how I was setting up the actual Fragment oddly enough.

Comment: I'm marking this up still just because I think its still relevant to improving the code and getting rid of this categorization of issues that could go wrong it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can only have 1 observable per event type.

Adding a second one like in your case removes the previous one.

Try commenting out everything but one `RxTextView.textChanges(txtEmail)`.

See the discussion on this issue: [only one observable at a time?](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/issues/146)

Comment: Yes I did remove the other textChange emissions to no avail.  Looking through [the following](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/morihacky/android/rxjava/fragments/FormValidationCombineLatestFragment.java) which seems popular and often linked to as an example.

Comment: By the way coming back to this more recently RxTextView.textChanges can have multiple observables you just need share operator to allow multiple subscriptions.  If you have two usages of the textChanges for the same view, there are issues with that.

Comment: @EvanAnger yes, I think you can only have one observable, because adding more clears the previous ones. As you said, the best way to solve it is by creating only one observable and sharing it, instead of creating multiple ones like in your question.